# Как правильно: точка или И?

Tags: пунктуация, грамотная-речь

Писал письмо по работе, возник спор с руководителем.
Немного преамбулы для понимания.
Есть "главный" протокол там был пункт, скажем № 9 и гласил он - провести совещание, определить.... Для исполнения этого пункта было организовано совещание, по результатам которого "родился" еще один протокол уже с конкретными руководствами к действию.
Письмом требовалось сообщить, что с целью исполнения пункта № 9 "главного" протокола, на основании пункта .. второго протокола прошу .....

Текст письма:
"Во исполнение пункта протокола ....(точка, имеется ввиду "главный" протокол) На основании пункта протокола...(Следующее предложение. Тут имеется ввиду второй протокол) прошу...."

Мой руководитель сказал написать 
"Во исполнение пункта протокола И на основании"

Таким образом, весь вопрос точка или запятая. Как правильно?
По его версии, точка полностью лишает смысла этот абзац и делает его недоступным для понимания. По моей же версии оба варианта корректны.

Возможно я ошибаюсь, но очень хочется узнать правду. 
Огромная просьба дать обоснованный комментарий, а не субъективное мнение.

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, пожалуйста, отметьте его [как принятый](/help/accepted-answer) (галочка рядом с ответом) и поставьте ему значок ▲.

Answer (score 1):

Если это текст письма, то оформление предложения должно быть таким: **Во исполнение пункта  № 9 протокола (название и дата) и на основании  протокола ...**

Точка ставится только в конце предложения, также иногда применяется при оформлении перечней: http://orthographia.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=145#pp145

Одиночный союз И связывает два однородных обстоятельства, поэтому запятая не ставится.

Пример первой части: https://arb.ru/b2b/news/vo_ispolnenie_punkta_2_protokola_soveshchaniya_u_zamestitelya_predsedatelya_prav-46711/

Во исполнение пункта 2 Протокола совещания у Заместителя Председателя Правительства Российской Федерации - Министра финансов Российской Федерации А.Л. Кудрина от 7 ноября 2007 года № КА-П13-4 пр...

Answer (score 0):

> "Во исполнение пункта протокола ....(точка, имеется ввиду "главный"
>   протокол) На основании пункта протокола...(Следующее предложение. Тут
>   имеется ввиду второй протокол) прошу...."

Нет, так не пройдет. Это вопрос, конечно, не русского языка, а делового этикета, но соблюдать его надо. "Рубленная" фраза хороша для заполнения поля "тема" или как заголовок. В тексте надо писать полными предложениями.

Но главное - я не вижу ни малейших смысловых недостатков в предложенной правке. А смотрится много лучше.